# How work stringBuilder.reverse?

Tags: java, string, reverse, tostring, stringbuilder

I thought revers should be equal "tor", but when I tried

```
String straight = stringBuilders[i].toString();
String reverse = stringBuilders[i].reverse().toString();
System.out.println("stringBuilders[i].reverse().toString() = " +  stringBuilders[i].reverse().toString()
+ " reverse = " + reverse + "    straight = " + straight + 
" rev == str ? " + reverse.equals(straight));
```

I got such result

```
stringBuilders[i].reverse().toString() = rot, reverse = tor, straight = tor, rev == str? false
```

Why?

`rev == str ?` gives output as `false`
How can be that

```
stringBuilders[i].reverse().toString() = rot, reverse = tor,
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the output you got? You should be getting either rot,tor,rot or tor,rot,tor, depending on the original value of the StringBuilder.

Comment: Magic is solved. "rot" is the first word in file, so it has the utf-16 BOM. that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem might be that `straight` uses index `j`, while the rest of the code uses index `i`.

Here is your code as an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("tor");
String straight = stringBuilder.toString();
String reverse = stringBuilder.reverse().toString();
System.out.println("stringBuilders[i].reverse().toString() = " +  stringBuilder.reverse().toString() +
                   " reverse = " + reverse +
                   "    straight = " + straight +
                   " rev == str? " + reverse.equals(straight));
```

Output is:

```
stringBuilders[i].reverse().toString() = tor reverse = rot    straight = tor rev == str? false
```

That is not the output you showed.

Anyway, your main problem is that [`reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29):

> Causes this character sequence to be **replaced** by the reverse of the sequence.

So, your first call to `reverse()` makes the `stringBuilder` have the value `rot`, which is also the value assigned to the `reverse` variable.

Your second call to `reverse()` in the print statement reverse it back to the value `tor`, which is then the value printed.

Comment: + was not equal because of "rot" is the first word in file, so it has the utf-16 BOM.

Answer (score 0):

> stringBuilders[i].reverse().toString() = ﻿rot, reverse = tor﻿,

StringBuilder is mutable so each time you call `reverse()` it flips the characters end to end.